# Rust: Create an Iterator out of Default and Succ?

Tags: iterator, rust

I have the following code in [a repo](https://github.com/bfops/playform/blob/master/src/id_allocator.rs):

```
impl<Id> IdAllocator<Id> where
  Id : Clone + Default + Add<u32, Id>,
{
  pub fn new() -> IdAllocator<Id> {
    IdAllocator {
      next: Default::default()
    }
  }

  // Produce an Id that hasn't been produced yet by this object.
  pub fn allocate(&mut self) -> Id {
    let ret = self.next.clone();
    self.next = self.next + 1;
    ret
  }
}
```

But it seems a little clumsy, especially since the `Add` instance is only used as a `succ` function (generating the next value in sequence). Is there some `Succ` class I can use? And if so, is there already some `Iterator` construction somewhere in the standard library that already does this `Default`+`Succ` pattern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately, there is no `Succ`-like thing in the standard library. The closest thing you can find is [`range()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.range.html) family of iterators, however, it uses `Add` and `One` numeric traits to generate items. You can do it this way (the idea is basically the same as yours, but this version is slightly more generic due to `One` trait usage):

```
use std::num::One;
use std::default::Default;

struct IdAllocator<T> {
    current: T
}

impl<T: Default> IdAllocator<T> {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new() -> IdAllocator<T> {
        IdAllocator {
            current: Default::default()
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Add<T, T>+One+Clone> Iterator<T> for IdAllocator<T> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let next = self.current + One::one();
        self.current = next.clone();
        Some(next)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = IdAllocator::<uint>::new();
    for i in a.take(10) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

(try it [here](http://is.gd/HUUngU))

Comment: I totally forgot about `One`! I'm still not particularly happy that I can't get rid of the `Add` requirement, but that's at least a step up. Thanks!